# Image processing using conv-neural net

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, convolution, python, machine-learning

Okay I am starting to understand the idea of neural networks but I still haven't been able to understand the use/benefits/implementation of convolutional neural networks especially for image processing.

What I don't understand is how to detect an object of different size.

Say we have a weights matrix of 50*50 and a face in the training set which is of 50*50 size . Now when you take the weighted sum of the matrix it will return a particular value say "X" . So now I understand the idea is to run the weights matrix over the entire image to get a lock over a region which gives a weighted sum of ~"X" now you have detected a face.

If the above mentioned understanding is true Then how is that an image of size 25*25 going to churn out a value anywhere clone to "X" . So the basic question is how to deal with relative sizes of the image .

If possible please suggest some good tutorials for the same .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, CNNs are typically used with identical sized inputs. So, you resize your input to a constant size, no matter what.

Next, detecting an object and recognizing an object over many samples are different tasks. For object detection, you could be better of with [R-CNNs](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/papers/r-cnn-cvpr.pdf). Its sources are also [available](https://github.com/rbgirshick/rcnn) and there is a [Caffe tutorial for R-CNNs](http://tutorial.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/caffe-cvpr15-detection.pdf). Of course there are many other works on the same topic. For example, [this one](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Erhan_Scalable_Object_Detection_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf).

Comment: As in say like we have an image of 50*50 , with in the image there is a face in the background which is made using 20*20. So how would the weights matrix return the same value for a face .

I read some where that we can resize the same image so that there might come a time when the face is enlarged to fit a 50*50 region .
But i dont find this a very efficient way of doing the same.

Comment: No it's not efficient. Your network should be trained with scaled samples of faces to do that. You should also learn it.

Comment: Okay so say an object say face would be having a range of values which is applicable

Comment: Thanks buddy , now I have another question about back propagation.

Comment: Like how do I go about it using gradient descent method and why exactly do we need a sigmoid function

Comment: Please read the papers for that. You don't necessarily need sigmoid, you only need activation functions such as RELU ( http://www.quora.com/What-is-special-about-rectifier-neural-units-used-in-NN-learning )